# adding keyboard QWERTY with Englisch-US and Russian keys

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I have replaced the keyboard of my Dell E5410 laptop to a new QWERTY keyboard with English-US and Russian keys.

How can I add a proper keyboard in Windows 10. I want to work with all keys/symbols of the keyboard. I can add the english language with US keyboard, but can't add a proper one which can handle all keys.

[image: The Keyboard Layout]

Comment: Are you expecting to use English and Russian simultaneously? The standard for Windows is to install separate English and Russian input methods and switch between them as needed.

Comment: See e.g. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-your-keyboard-layout-245c49b8-f856-7fd7-2cf5-41e54c66f5b3. Please [edit] your question and add a detailed description how you imagine to use the keyboard with both English and Russian symbols.